# JRC JJ1000 + dronekit >> ERROR:dronekit.mavlink:Exception in MAVLink input loop

Tags: python, dronekit

I am trying to connect JRC JJ1000 drone using dronekit + python.
when executing the connect command:

```
dronekit.connect('com3', baud=115200, heartbeat_timeout=30)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:dronekit.mavlink:Exception in MAVLink input loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\dronekit\mavlink.py", line 211, in mavlink_thread_in
    fn(self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\dronekit\__init__.py", line 1371, in listener
    self._heartbeat_error)
dronekit.APIException: No heartbeat in 5 seconds, aborting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\dronekit\__init__.py", line 3166, in connect
    vehicle.initialize(rate=rate, heartbeat_timeout=heartbeat_timeout)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\dronekit\__init__.py", line 2275, in initialize
    raise APIException('Timeout in initializing connection.')
dronekit.APIException: Timeout in initializing connection.
```

I left no store unturned but no progress. I also tried both Python 2.7 and 3.7 with same result.

Comment: did you try with other ports - ie. `com1`, `com2`, `com4`, etc. ?

Comment: yes, com3; others I didn't

Comment: I never use this module but in documentation I see `com14` in table on https://dronekit-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/connecting_vehicle.html#get-started-connecting

Comment: any working library you suggest?

Comment: com14 must be an example; thought I doubt there is 14 serial ports in PC

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the same error. I am using some custom code in a docker container to run simulations with dronekit and ArduPilot. The error is intermittent. So far it seems like the only way to get the error to stop is to:

- Close all docker containers.
- Open windows task manager and wait for vmmem to lower memory usage (5-10m).
- Try again.

Maybe the problems are related somehow. To me it seems like the connection might be in use by a previous instance and it was not properly close. Since waiting for vmmem to free up resources appears to fix it. I would prefer a better solution if anyone finds one!

We are using python code like this to connect:

```
from dronekit import connect
 ...
# try to connect 5 times
while connected == False and fails < 5:
    try:
        vehicle = connect(connection_string, wait_ready=True)
    except:
        fails += 1 
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Failed to connect to local mavlink sleeping for 3 seconds")
    else: 
        connected = True
```

Where the connection_string is of the form:

```
"tcp:host:port"
```

Also, the documentation states "If the baud rate is not set correctly, connect may fail with a timeout error. It is best to set the baud rate explicitly." Are you sure that you have the correct baud rate?